# How to fill a .xlsm sheet with c#

Tags: c#, excel, xlsx

I need to fill the checkboxes of an existing .xlsm file with C#. And there is a button that calculates the points of checkboxes and I need to execute that too.

I don't understand how that .xlsm file works. It's possible to do that?
[image]

---

Some code:

```cs
public static void Fill(string originalFile)
{
    var excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    var workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(originalFile);
    var sheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet;

    //Normal fields works fine
    sheet.Cells[10, "B"] = "Some name value";
    sheet.Cells[11, "B"] = "Some document value";

    //But, how to check the checkbox?
    //I don't know where are the cells and I don't known what the value to set. 
    //These fields are protected, and I think that it's not possible to fill that way
    //sheet.Cells[??, "??"] = "true or 1???";

    //And how to call the calculate button? There is something like that?
    //sheet.Buttons("Calculate").Invoke();

    sheet.SaveAs("Output.xlsm");
    excel.Quit();
}
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Comment: Thanks @mjwills! I just put some code